# Python nested dictionary update in loop

Tags: python

The following code would generate a nested dictionary. But

```
   l = [1,2,3,4]
   n_dict = current = {}
   for n in l:
      current[n] = {}       # would n_dict get update?
      # print(current)      # just to check
      # print(n_dict)       # just to check
      current = current[n]  # would n_dict get update?
      # print(current)      # just to check
      # print(n_dict)       # just to check
   print(n_dict)
```

n_dict has become a nested dictionary while current is not. So what's the rule that n_dict will or will not get update inside the foo-loop (see the two question lines)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try running it? What happened?

Comment: of course I did run it before I asked. n_dict = {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}. You can verifiy

Comment: So have you not answered your own question?

Comment: Seems Mark's answer of current reference to n_dict was deleted or disappeared. I got that n_dict is not referenced to current after current=current[n]. But n_dict is still referenced to current[n], why is that?

Comment: I'd suggest you run this through a debugger or e.g. http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you how the above code is working -

```
n_dict = current = {}
```

When you do this both n_dict and current will point to the same empty dictionary.

Now, in for loop, see this line -

```
current = current[n]
```

Here, you're changing the current variable it now points to an empty dict.
You're using the current variable to modify the original dict and that original dict can be access by n_dict pointer.